# keep elements's dimensions unchanged, regardless of border width

Tags: html, css

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) border should be included in element's height if `box-sizing:border-box;` is used.

In the example below I changed `border-top` and the element's height **is changed**

How to keep elements's dimensions unchanged, regardless of border width?

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('titleact');
});
```

```css
.title{
box-sizing:border-box;
border-top: 2px solid blue;
padding:9px;
}

.titleact{
border-top:10px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like GolezTrol said you need to set the height explicitly.
Or you could extract the extra border space from the top padding to prevent the content from "jumping" (2px + 9px == 10px + 1px):

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('titleact');
});
```

```css
.title{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 9px;
}

.titleact{
  border-top: 10px dashed red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a size at all. `box-sizing` is used to indicate that the width or height you *explicitly* set, will be measured including or excluding the border. In this case, no dimensions are set explicitly, and the element will just scale with its contents.

-edit-

If, like you commented, you can't set a specific height, it also means you can't use border-box like that for your solution. You can however trick it a bit with a placeholder. In the example below, I've used the `::before` pseudo-element to stand in for the border. The element is fixed to 10px, and the border will be either 2px or 10px depending on the given class. The rest of the contents of the `.title` element can still scale vertically as you want.

Maybe it can be done a bit more elegantly than this, but at least I hope you get the idea.

```js
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('titleact');
});
```

```css
.title {
  padding: 0 9px 9px 9px;
}

.title::before{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.titleact::before {
  border-bottom:10px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: but I can't know the height in advance. It depends on element's content

Comment: Yes, that's a tricky situation. You want to have a dynamically sized element, where _some_ of the influencers of that size (border width) are ignored and the rest should be taken into account. I don't think the out of the box functionality (no pun intended), won't help you there. You would probably need to make some placeholder, or use a `::before` pseudo-element instead of the border.

Comment: could you give me an example using `::before`, pls. I need to mark clicked element, but without changing its height

Comment: thanks a lot, but now margins are changed. I think this will push all previous elements

Comment: You want the border to fold in? I didn't get that, but in that case, I think you should use @sn3p's answer. For a next time, it may be a good idea to include a picture in the question, and provider a bit of context about the surroundings, so people like me won't make false assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to re-create the same using background and gradient and you won't have any issue:

```js
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('titleact');
});
```

```css
.title {
  background:linear-gradient(blue,blue) top/100% 2px no-repeat; 
  padding: 10px;
}

.titleact {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,red 0, red 15px,transparent 15px, transparent 25px) top/100% 10px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
```